# Need regex to fix Construct 2.8 name-less

Tags: python, regex, pack

In [Construct 2.8](http://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) fields became name-less and I need a script that can more or less automatically translate, similar to 2to3 python script. For full disclosure, I am the maintainer. This is not just for me but for the entire community.

What needs to be translated:

```
ULInt32 -> Int32ub  (actually its from {U,S}{B,L}Int{8,16,24,32,64})
field("name") -> "name" / field
Struct("name", ..., ...) -> "name" / Struct(..., ...)

(still adding...)
```

The regex tool I used previously:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re, os, sys

def processfolder(top): 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.py'):
                processfile(os.path.join(root, f))
        for d in dirs:
            processfolder(os.path.join(root, d))

def processfile(fname):
    print(fname+'... ', end='')
    with open(fname, 'rt') as f:
        txt = f.read()
    txt = re.sub(r'???', lambda s: s.expand(r'\1'), txt)
    with open(fname, 'wt') as f:
        f.write(txt)
    print('done')


processfolder(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: What did you try instead of `r'???'` ?

Comment: I do not speek regex, need someone write those format strings.